# SharePoint 2010 BaseFieldControl Duplicates first item in list when in DisplayMode

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have come across a problem when using the BaseFieldControl that is driving me to distraction.

Essentinally I am trying to convert a list into a HTML table using the BaseFieldControl to render the fields.

When my table renders it writes out the correct number of lines BUT the data in each line is always the same as the first item in the list.

When I change the ControlMode property from SPControlMode.Display to SPControlMode.Edit the list renders correctly ( apart from being in Edit mode )

When my code running with ControlMode set to SPControlMode.Display  I can actually get at the correct value in the BaseFieldControl.ItemFieldValue property but the wretched BaseFieldControl still insists on rendering the first item in the list!

I've also installed the web part on a SharePoint foundation and SharePoint 2010 server and I get the same results!

Finally I've googled around and found other peoples examples.  Unfortunately when I try other dev's code ( unmodified ) I get exactly the same results!

This is what I'm doing.  Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

foreach (string f in list.DefaultView.ViewFields)
            {

```
            TableCell c = new TableCell();
            var i = item[f];
            if (i != null)
            {
                SPField spf = item.Fields.GetField(f);
                BaseFieldControl bfc = spf.FieldRenderingControl; 
                bfc.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;

                bfc.Value = bfc.ItemFieldValue;

                bfc.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                bfc.FieldName = spf.Title;
                bfc.ListId = list.ID;
                bfc.ItemId = item.ID;
                SPContext context = SPContext.GetContext(this.Context, item.ID, list.ID, SPContext.Current.Web);

                bfc.ItemContext = context;
                bfc.RenderContext = context;
                bfc.EnableViewState = true;
                bfc.Visible = true;


                c.Controls.Add(bfc);

            }
            else
            {
                c.Text = "NULL";
            }
            r.Cells.Add(c);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it.  Turns out to be a problem with the SPWeb object.  I had grabbed it from SPContext and passed it through as a reference to my method.

When I stopped doing that but instead created it within the method ( and created it once per item in the list ) it all worked fine.

Very strange.